# php check if value exist on all multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Currently going crazy on how to do this, basicly I have a multidimensional array and need a code to check all values and if value exists in all arrays than to return the result.

Parents **visitPoints,islands,animals** will always exist, although some times empty, the second level columns are dynamic so keys 20,35,57 change and there content.

```
$array = [
    'visitPoints'=>[
        20=>[2,5,6,8,10,11],
        35=>[2,5,6],
        57=>[1],
    ],
    'islands'=>[
        20=>[5,10,11],
        35=>[5,6]
    ],
    'animals'=>[
        20=>[5,11],
        35=>[]
    ]
];
```

And the result I'm looking for is this:

```
$result = [
    20=>[5,11],
    35=>[],
    57=>[]
];
```

was playing around with **call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $array)** but could not get the result I'm looking for.

Here is the sample link: https://3v4l.org/meX5p

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue

Comment: @ADyson tried some options offline but not worth sharing since they make no sense.

Comment: Will all columns always exist in all arrays? Can we always trust that second level columns will be available (eg. `20` and `35`)?

Comment: Is the depth always known? Is the structure always the same?

Comment: what will always exist is the parents visitPoints,islands,animals although some times empty, the second level columns are dynamic so keys 20,35 change and there content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolate the first subset and apply it to the result, then iterate the remaining subsets by following the result array's keys and filter the respective rows with `array_intersect()` falling back to an empty array when a result row is not found for a respective key.  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9Drtq))

```
$result = array_shift($array) ?? [];
foreach ($array as $rows) {
    foreach ($result as $k => $row) {
        $result[$k] = array_values(array_intersect($row, $rows[$k] ?? []));
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

I'll include null coalescing on the result in case the input array is empty.

Comment: any chance we can condition if key is not in all 3 to not return it, here is an example https://3v4l.org/VS2LE  the key 57 shows only on visitPoints and not in rest, so its not valid and must be ignored.

Comment: This was my initial concern. I'll update my answer after you update your question.  Might the unique key be found only in a later subarray? The more challenging your [mcve], the better the answers will be.

Comment: I appreciate ur time and help.

Comment: can I replace $result[$k] for $row ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, good catch. I cleaned up my snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this? Test it [here](https://onlinephp.io/c/d2f1b).

```
$array = [
    'visitPoints'=>[
        20=>[2,5,6,8,10,11],
        35=>[2,5,6]
    ],
    'islands'=>[
        20=>[5,10,11],
        35=>[5,6]
    ],
    'animals'=>[
        20=>[5,11],
        35=>[]
    ]
];

function checkExisting($arr) {
    $result = [];
    $pass = 0;
    foreach($arr as $firstLvlKey=>$firstLvlArray) {
        $pass++;
        foreach($firstLvlArray as $secondLvlKey=>$secondLvlArray) {
            if($pass === 1) {
                $result[$secondLvlKey] = $secondLvlArray;
            } else {
                $result[$secondLvlKey] = array_intersect($result[$secondLvlKey],$secondLvlArray);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $result;
}

print_r(checkExisting($array));
```

---

**EDIT**

I noticed that this will keep the indices from the third level of the initial array (in this case, indices `1` and `5`). If you don't mind that, you can use the example as it was given. If you do need to reset the indices (i.e. `0 => 5`, `1=> 11`, etc), then you can do something like this:

```
$array = [...];

function checkExisting($arr) {
    $result = [];
    $pass = 0;
    foreach(...) {
        $pass++;
        foreach(...) {
            if($pass === 1) {
                $result[$secondLvlKey] = $secondLvlArray;
            } else {
                // the part below matters - wrap everything in array_values(...)
                $result[$secondLvlKey] = array_values(array_intersect($result[$secondLvlKey],$secondLvlArray);)
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $result;
}

print_r(checkExisting($array));
```